# How do repeat a section of code using a while loop and use each of the "Counts"?

Tags: python, tkinter

Am trying to make a gui that has 16 buttons that each write to a text box. Am trying to condense into a few lines instead of having an individual button per value i.e using a while loop to repeat one set of code sixteen times.

Ive tried tieing the "count value" to be the one written to the text box but it only prints the last value 15/f for each of the buttons even if the button says 0-15/f.

```
for x in range(1,16):
    Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")

    btn = tk.Button(scframe.interior, height=1, width=10, relief=tk.RAISED,                                             #Text button to write the other 15 hexadecimal values
                text= Address_Hex ,command=lambda i=i,x=x: Write_Hex())
    btn.pack(padx=10, pady=2, side=tk.TOP)


def Write_Hex():                                                                                                         #The writing fuction
       Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")
       T.insert(tk.END, Address_Hex)
```

The desired result is to have a few lines of code able to create 16 buttons that write their corresponding value i.e button zero writes 0, f writes f etc.

Comment: Any reason you're using x for the loop variable? The convention is to use i, then j, then k.

Comment: Where is the value for `i` coming from in that's being used in the `command=lambda i=i,x=x: Write_Hex()` part — and why is it being passed as an argument to the `lambda` function?

Comment: Any particular reason for the convention of i, then j and k? i was using x since i was using i later.

Comment: In response to the second comment, am still new to python and was using a line of code i saw that worked so  some of it i have no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Write_Hex` needs to take the `x` that you're binding in the lambda as an argument:

```
for x in range(1,16):
   Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")

   btn = tk.Button(scframe.interior, height=1, width=10, relief=tk.RAISED,                                             #Text button to write the other 15 hexadecimal values
               text= Address_Hex ,command=lambda i=i,x=x: Write_Hex(x))
   btn.pack(padx=10, pady=2, side=tk.TOP)


def Write_Hex(x):                                                                                                         #The writing fuction
      Address_Hex = hex(x).lstrip("0x")
      T.insert(tk.END, Address_Hex)
```

Comment: Worked, could you do some thing similar with a list containing  strings for example a list with number 1-15, and words such as rol a, sta, x etc?

Comment: Sure - if your list of strings is in `lst` then `for x in lst`:... etc. Not sure I completely understand the question though. Also since you're not using the value of `i` in your `lambda` you can remove that from your command. Also if you're wondering what the `lambda` song and dance is about here, this is a decent article that goes through the motivation and why it's necessary to bind `x` to the default arg of the lambda for the closure to work right: http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2016/01/for-each-loops-should-define-new.html

Comment: Am new to python programming, hopefully that explains the falterings of my questions, and was adapting those lines of code from elsewhere for my purposes. Am still learning so thank you for the link for more information.

Comment: The whole binding to the default arg of a lambda to get around pythons late binding is not exactly intro level stuff either so you're doing well!

Comment: Appreciate the compliment. Thank you for giving me a little more insight, i actually had no idea about the late binding issue and my lack of terminology to explain it in order to get an answer helps me considerable to understand it.